# Lottery - Avoid unecessary subsets from a set when aiming prizes of lower order

Tags: co.combinatorics

I have a Lottery app and I'm implementing a feature to optimize the number of bets that are necessary to cover a subset of numbers since they can repeat on several bets.

**What I have:**

Supposing a lottery where you can select 6 numbers from 1 to 60. Then, 6 numbers are draw and you win if you correctly guess 4 or 5 or all 6 numbers.

When creating a bet, you can "emulate" a bet with 9 numbers by finding all possible combinations with them (combination without repetition). In this example:

$$
C_{6}^{9} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = \frac{9!}{6!(9-6)!} = 84
$$

In other words, I need to create 84 bets to cover all combinations of 6 numbers among those 9.

I've already created the code to calculate and find all combinations.

**Feature I want to implement**

Supposing I not interested in the main prize (6) but on the lowest prize: 4. In this case, I don't need to create all 84 bets. With fewer bets, I can cover all combinations of 4 numbers from those 9 I started.

In the end, I want two things:

1. Find the minimum amount of bets (with 6 numbers) I need to create in order to cover all possible combinations of 4 numbers among those 9.
2. Generate those bets.

**Some example**

I found some samples on the internet but I didn't manage to implement the algorithm or find the math behind it. In the sample I found:

The 9 numbers I want to bet:
$$
S = \\{ 07, 12, 24, 32, 37, 41, 42, 54, 55 \\}
$$

Instead of creating 84 bets, I can create 12 bet and I would still win the 4-numbers prize if 4 of those 9 numbers are correct.

**Result**

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $T_1 = \\{ 07, 12, 24, 32, 37, 41 \\}$ | $T_2 = \\{ 07, 12, 24, 42, 54, 55 \\}$ | $T_3 = \\{ 07, 12, 32, 37, 42, 54 \\} $ |
| $T_4 = \\{ 07, 12, 32, 41, 54, 55 \\}$ | $T_5 = \\{ 07, 12, 37, 41, 42, 55 \\}$ | $T_6 = \\{ 07, 24, 32, 37, 54, 55 \\}$ |
| $T_7 = \\{ 07, 24, 32, 41, 42, 55 \\}$ | $T_8 = \\{ 07, 24, 37, 41, 42, 54 \\}$ | $T_9 = \\{ 12, 24, 32, 37, 42, 55 \\}$ |
| $T_10 = \\{ 12, 24, 32, 41, 42, 54 \\}$ | $T_11 = \\{ 12, 24, 37, 41, 54, 55 \\}$ | $T_12 = \\{ 32, 37, 41, 42, 54, 55 \\}$ |

I would appreciate if someone give some direction because I'm not being able to move forward

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lotteries

Comment: For the optimal situation in which every four-element subset occurs as a subset of exactly one of $T_i$'s, see the theory of $t$-designs (with $\lambda=1$), e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design or https://webspace.maths.qmul.ac.uk/l.h.soicher/designtheory.org/library/encyc/tdes/g,

Answer (score 1):

This might be better asked on MathStackExchange, although the underlying question leads to interesting problems. You might look at the following excerpt from Jordan Ellenberg's book *[How Not to Be Wrong: The Power of Mathematical Thinking](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ekpmann/ellenberg.pdf)* that describes a strategy for buying lottery tickets to minimize the variance. Not exactly the question that you're asking, but of a similar flavor, since one wants to avoid duplication.

Comment: Thank you @JoeSilverman.. I'll definitely take a look